# Access phpMyAdmin main page in Amazon EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, phpmyadmin

I have an amazon EC2 amazon-linux instance running.

I installed phpmyadmin (correctly I think, I followed these steps https://superuser.com/questions/291230/how-to-install-phpmyadmin-on-linux-ec2-instance), but when I access http:// *myelasticIP* /phpmyadmin i just see a file list, with everything in my phpmyadmin folder.

What do I have to do to view phpmyadmin main page??? I know it must be a stupid question, but I dont know what else to do...

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Silly question, I just had to install php in my EC2 instance. Obviously is not installed by default. 
Hope it helped someone

Comment: Typically, all you have to do after installing phpmyadmin is to hit: http://your-ec2-host/phpmyadmin should've mentioned this.